# Refresh div every second

Tags: html

this is the source code of a webpage made for an ESP8266 Web server ("@t", "@a", "@p" and "@h" are replaced by actual values using a C++ function):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Weather Station</title>
    <style>
            html{
            font-family: Helvetica;
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 0px auto;
            text-align: center;
            }
            body{
            margin-top: 50px;
            }
            h1{
            color: #444444;
            margin: 50px auto 30px;
            }
            p{
            font-size: 24px;
            color: #444444;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            }
    </style>
    
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="webpage\">
        <h1>Weather Station</h1>
        <p>Temperature: @t &deg;C</p>
        <p>Humidity: @h %</p>
        <p>Pressure: @p hPa</p>
        <p>Altitude: @a m</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is it possible to refresh just that one div (the values part) in the source?
Thanks.

EDIT: if anyone is curious about how everything works, this is the main source file:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0-or-later
/*++

Copyright (c) 2022 Nicolò Cantori

Module Name:

    main.cpp

Abstract:

    Main module for weather station Wi-Fi server.

Author:

    Nicolò Cantori (ncant)      03-July-2022

Revision History:

--*/

#include <Arduino.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>
#include <Adafruit_BME280.h>
#include "data.hpp"

#define SEA_LEVEL_PRESSURE_HPA (1013.25)

void handle_OnConnect();
void handle_NotFound();

Adafruit_BME280 bme;

float temperature, humidity, pressure, altitude;

//-- Put your SSID & password here: ----------------------------------------
const char* ssid  = "Wi-Fi_Test";
const char* psw   = "nicolo04";
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------

ESP8266WebServer server(80);

String webpage_buf = "";


void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    delay(100);

    // Build & store our webpage into a String variable:

    Serial.println("Starting up. Please wait...");

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < webpage_html_len; i++)
    {
        webpage_buf += (char)webpage_html[i];
    }

    // Initialize sensor:
    bme.begin(0x76);

    // Connect to local Wi-Fi network:

    Serial.print("Connecting to "); Serial.print(ssid);
    WiFi.begin(ssid, psw);

    // Check if board is connected to Wi-Fi network:

   while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
   {
        delay(1000);
        Serial.print(".");
   }

    // Done.

    Serial.println("\nWi-Fi connection enstablished!");
    Serial.print("Got IP: "); Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
    
    server.on("/", handle_OnConnect);
    server.onNotFound(handle_NotFound);

    server.begin();
    Serial.println("HTTP server is up.");
}


void loop()
{
    server.handleClient();
}


String SendHTML(
    const float temperature,
    const float humidity,
    const float pressure,
    const float altitude
    )

/*++

Routine Description:

    Makes a webpage using the given arguments.

--*/

{
    webpage_buf.replace("@t", String(temperature));
    webpage_buf.replace("@h", String(humidity));
    webpage_buf.replace("@p", String(pressure));
    webpage_buf.replace("@a", String(altitude));

    return webpage_buf;
}


void handle_OnConnect()
{
    temperature = bme.readTemperature();
    humidity    = bme.readHumidity();
    pressure    = bme.readPressure() / 100.0F;
    altitude    = bme.readAltitude(SEA_LEVEL_PRESSURE_HPA);

    server.send(200, "text/html", SendHTML(temperature,
                                           humidity,
                                           pressure,
                                           altitude));
}


void handle_NotFound()
{
    server.send(200, "text/plain", "Not Found.");
}
```

data.hpp contains the converted webpage data instead:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0-or-later
/*++

Copyright (c) 2022 Nicolò Cantori

Module Name:

    data.hpp

Abstract:

    Webpage Unicode data blob.

Author:

    Nicolò Cantori (ncant)      03-July-2022

Revision History:

--*/

#pragma once

unsigned char webpage_html[] = {
  0x3c, 0x21, 0x44, 0x4f, 0x43, 0x54, 0x59, 0x50, 0x45, 0x20, 0x68, 0x74,
  0x6d, 0x6c, 0x3e, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x3c, 0x68, 0x74, 0x6d, 0x6c, 0x20, 0x6c,
  0x61, 0x6e, 0x67, 0x3d, 0x22, 0x65, 0x6e, 0x22, 0x3e, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x20,
  0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x3c, 0x68, 0x65,
  0x61, 0x64, 0x3e, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20,
  0x20, 0x3c, 0x6d, 0x65, 0x74, 0x61, 0x20, 0x63, 0x68, 0x61, 0x72, 0x73,
  0x65, 0x74, 0x3d, 0x22, 0x55, 0x54, 0x46, 0x2d, 0x38, 0x22, 0x3e, 0x0d,
  0x0a, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x3c, 0x6d, 0x65,
  0x74, 0x61, 0x20, 0x6e, 0x61, 0x6d, 0x65, 0x3d, 0x22, 0x76, 0x69, 0x65,
  0x77, 0x70, 0x6f, 0x72, 0x74, 0x22, 0x20, 0x63, 0x6f, 0x6e, 0x74, 0x65,
  0x6e, 0x74, 0x3d, 0x22, 0x77, 0x69, 0x64, 0x74, 0x68, 0x3d, 0x64, 0x65,
  0x76, 0x69, 0x63, 0x65, 0x2d, 0x77, 0x69, 0x64, 0x74, 0x68, 0x2c, 0x20,
  0x69, 0x6e, 0x69, 0x74, 0x69, 0x61, 0x6c, 0x2d, 0x73, 0x63, 0x61, 0x6c,
  0x65, 0x3d, 0x31, 0x22, 0x3e, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20,
  0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x3c, 0x74, 0x69, 0x74, 0x6c, 0x65, 0x3e, 0x57, 0x65,
  0x61, 0x74, 0x68, 0x65, 0x72, 0x20, 0x53, 0x74, 0x61, 0x74, 0x69, 0x6f,
  0x6e, 0x3c, 0x2f, 0x74, 0x69, 0x74, 0x6c, 0x65, 0x3e, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x20,
  0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x3c, 0x73, 0x74, 0x79, 0x6c, 0x65, 0x3e, 0x0d, 0x0a,
  0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20,
  0x68, 0x74, 0x6d, 0x6c, 0x7b, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20,
  0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x66, 0x6f, 0x6e, 0x74, 0x2d,
  0x66, 0x61, 0x6d, 0x69, 0x6c, 0x79, 0x3a, 0x20, 0x48, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x76,
  0x65, 0x74, 0x69, 0x63, 0x61, 0x3b, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20,
  0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x64, 0x69, 0x73, 0x70,
  0x6c, 0x61, 0x79, 0x3a, 0x20, 0x69, 0x6e, 0x6c, 0x69, 0x6e, 0x65, 0x2d,
  0x62, 0x6c, 0x6f, 0x63, 0x6b, 0x3b, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20,
  0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x6d, 0x61, 0x72, 0x67,
  0x69, 0x6e, 0x3a, 0x20, 0x30, 0x70, 0x78, 0x20, 0x61, 0x75, 0x74, 0x6f,
  0x3b, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20,
  0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x74, 0x65, 0x78, 0x74, 0x2d, 0x61, 0x6c, 0x69, 0x67,
  0x6e, 0x3a, 0x20, 0x63, 0x65, 0x6e, 0x74, 0x65, 0x72, 0x3b, 0x0d, 0x0a,
  0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20,
  0x7d, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20,
  0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x62, 0x6f, 0x64, 0x79, 0x7b, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x20, 0x20,
  0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x6d, 0x61,
  0x72, 0x67, 0x69, 0x6e, 0x2d, 0x74, 0x6f, 0x70, 0x3a, 0x20, 0x35, 0x30,
  0x70, 0x78, 0x3b, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20,
  0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x7d, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20,
  0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x68, 0x31, 0x7b, 0x0d,
  0x0a, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20,
  0x20, 0x63, 0x6f, 0x6c, 0x6f, 0x72, 0x3a, 0x20, 0x23, 0x34, 0x34, 0x34,
  0x34, 0x34, 0x34, 0x3b, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20,
  0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x6d, 0x61, 0x72, 0x67, 0x69, 0x6e,
  0x3a, 0x20, 0x35, 0x30, 0x70, 0x78, 0x20, 0x61, 0x75, 0x74, 0x6f, 0x20,
  0x33, 0x30, 0x70, 0x78, 0x3b, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20,
  0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x7d, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x20, 0x20,
  0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x70, 0x7b,
  0x0d, 0x0a, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20,
  0x20, 0x20, 0x66, 0x6f, 0x6e, 0x74, 0x2d, 0x73, 0x69, 0x7a, 0x65, 0x3a,
  0x20, 0x32, 0x34, 0x70, 0x78, 0x3b, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20,
  0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x63, 0x6f, 0x6c, 0x6f,
  0x72, 0x3a, 0x20, 0x23, 0x34, 0x34, 0x34, 0x34, 0x34, 0x34, 0x3b, 0x0d,
  0x0a, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20,
  0x20, 0x6d, 0x61, 0x72, 0x67, 0x69, 0x6e, 0x2d, 0x62, 0x6f, 0x74, 0x74,
  0x6f, 0x6d, 0x3a, 0x20, 0x31, 0x30, 0x70, 0x78, 0x3b, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x20,
  0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x7d,
  0x0d, 0x0a, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x3c, 0x2f, 0x73, 0x74, 0x79, 0x6c,
  0x65, 0x3e, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x3c, 0x21,
  0x2d, 0x2d, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x3c, 0x73, 0x63, 0x72,
  0x69, 0x70, 0x74, 0x20, 0x74, 0x79, 0x70, 0x65, 0x20, 0x3d, 0x20, 0x22,
  0x74, 0x65, 0x78, 0x74, 0x2f, 0x4a, 0x61, 0x76, 0x61, 0x73, 0x63, 0x72,
  0x69, 0x70, 0x74, 0x22, 0x3e, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20,
  0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x66, 0x75, 0x6e, 0x63, 0x74, 0x69, 0x6f, 0x6e, 0x20,
  0x41, 0x75, 0x74, 0x6f, 0x52, 0x65, 0x66, 0x72, 0x65, 0x73, 0x68, 0x28,
  0x74, 0x29, 0x20, 0x7b, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20,
  0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x73, 0x65, 0x74, 0x54, 0x69, 0x6d,
  0x65, 0x6f, 0x75, 0x74, 0x28, 0x22, 0x6c, 0x6f, 0x63, 0x61, 0x74, 0x69,
  0x6f, 0x6e, 0x2e, 0x72, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x6f, 0x61, 0x64, 0x28, 0x74, 0x72,
  0x75, 0x65, 0x29, 0x3b, 0x22, 0x2c, 0x20, 0x74, 0x29, 0x3b, 0x0d, 0x0a,
  0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x7d, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x20,
  0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x3c, 0x2f, 0x73, 0x63, 0x72, 0x69, 0x70, 0x74, 0x3e,
  0x0d, 0x0a, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x2d, 0x2d, 0x3e, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x20,
  0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x3c, 0x2f, 0x68,
  0x65, 0x61, 0x64, 0x3e, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x3c, 0x62,
  0x6f, 0x64, 0x79, 0x20, 0x6f, 0x6e, 0x6c, 0x6f, 0x61, 0x64, 0x20, 0x3d,
  0x20, 0x22, 0x4a, 0x61, 0x76, 0x61, 0x53, 0x63, 0x72, 0x69, 0x70, 0x74,
  0x3a, 0x41, 0x75, 0x74, 0x6f, 0x52, 0x65, 0x66, 0x72, 0x65, 0x73, 0x68,
  0x28, 0x31, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x29, 0x3b, 0x22, 0x3e, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x20,
  0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x3c, 0x64, 0x69, 0x76, 0x20,
  0x69, 0x64, 0x3d, 0x22, 0x77, 0x65, 0x62, 0x70, 0x61, 0x67, 0x65, 0x5c,
  0x22, 0x3e, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20,
  0x3c, 0x68, 0x31, 0x3e, 0x57, 0x65, 0x61, 0x74, 0x68, 0x65, 0x72, 0x20,
  0x53, 0x74, 0x61, 0x74, 0x69, 0x6f, 0x6e, 0x3c, 0x2f, 0x68, 0x31, 0x3e,
  0x0d, 0x0a, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x3c, 0x70,
  0x3e, 0x54, 0x65, 0x6d, 0x70, 0x65, 0x72, 0x61, 0x74, 0x75, 0x72, 0x65,
  0x3a, 0x20, 0x40, 0x74, 0x20, 0x26, 0x64, 0x65, 0x67, 0x3b, 0x43, 0x3c,
  0x2f, 0x70, 0x3e, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20,
  0x20, 0x3c, 0x70, 0x3e, 0x48, 0x75, 0x6d, 0x69, 0x64, 0x69, 0x74, 0x79,
  0x3a, 0x20, 0x40, 0x68, 0x20, 0x25, 0x3c, 0x2f, 0x70, 0x3e, 0x0d, 0x0a,
  0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x3c, 0x70, 0x3e, 0x50,
  0x72, 0x65, 0x73, 0x73, 0x75, 0x72, 0x65, 0x3a, 0x20, 0x40, 0x70, 0x20,
  0x68, 0x50, 0x61, 0x3c, 0x2f, 0x70, 0x3e, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20,
  0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x3c, 0x70, 0x3e, 0x41, 0x6c, 0x74, 0x69,
  0x74, 0x75, 0x64, 0x65, 0x3a, 0x20, 0x40, 0x61, 0x20, 0x6d, 0x3c, 0x2f,
  0x70, 0x3e, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20,
  0x3c, 0x2f, 0x64, 0x69, 0x76, 0x3e, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20,
  0x3c, 0x2f, 0x62, 0x6f, 0x64, 0x79, 0x3e, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x3c, 0x2f, 0x68,
  0x74, 0x6d, 0x6c, 0x3e
};

unsigned int webpage_html_len = 1168;
```

Comment: what, how are you loading this page via apache, nginx or just as a simple file access

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen Here's the fun part. You see, I have to tell the ESP board how to construct the webpage that it will then transmit. To do so, without modifying the original html source file, I have to convert the contents of the html file into (Unicode) hex, and then store these values into a char array. Doing so the board already "knows" how the webpage should be, and the only thing it will do is reconstruct it (using a String value) at runtime and then fetch the result into a function (that needs html data to be stored into a String variable).

Comment: You can add some JS to the page to re-fetch those values periodically but you will also have to modify the server to handle that request.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Well, I _can_ run JS scripts even with this (very awful) setup. JS works. I'm just missing the code to make it work

Comment: The ugly and quick solution is `setTimeout(() => window.location.reload(), 1000)`, a better solution would be to retrieve those values with ajax and update the dom, but you will need an endpoint for that, to return the new values. The question is, when you reload, will you get the new values or you will still get the old page

Comment: @Lk77 I'd still get new values, as the C++ function changes values independently from the html source.

Comment: Your original code has a bug, by the way, in that `webpage_buf` is only initialized from the `webpage_html` array once, so subsequent `.replace()`s won't do anything (since the placeholders had already been replaced).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have the web server return 2 pages. The main index page and a second page that returns the data as JSON. The main page can use Javascript to periodically load the 2nd page and update the fields in the main page.

Change the fields to spans to be updateable

```html
    <p>Temperature: <span id="temperature"></span> &deg;C</p>
    <p>Humidity: <span id="humidity"></span> %</p>
    <p>Pressure: <span id="pressure"></span> hPa</p>
    <p>Altitude: <span id="altitude"></span> m</p>
```

Then add the JS to fetch the data and update spans periodically

```js
<script>
    const update = () => {
        // Get the JSON data and set spans with the data
        fetch('http://127.0.0.1/get_data.json')
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(data => {
              document.getElementById("temperature").textContent = data.temperature;
              document.getElementById("humidity").textContent = data.humidity;
             // Repeat for others....
        });
    }
    // Update every 10 seconds
    setInterval(update, 10000);
    // Initial update
    update();
</script>
```

Then modify your server to return 2 pages. The first is the main page with the above stuff added. The second should be the data in JSON format.

```c++
void send_main_page() {
  server.send(200, "text/html", [text for main page as above]);
}

void send_data() {
  // Read data from sensors and build JSON string
  String json = "{\"temperature\":"
  json += bme.readTemperature();
  json += ",\"humidity\":";
  json += bme.readHumidity();
  // finish others
  json += "}";
  // You can also use a JSON library to build the JSON
  server.send(200, "application/json", json);
}

void setup(void){
  // Setup server....

  server.on("/", send_main_page);
  server.on("/get_data.json", send_data);

  // Finish setup
}
```

The JSON can look something like this:

```json
{
    "temperature": 32.0,
    "humidity": 50.0,
    "pressure": 20.0,
    "altitude": 10.0
}
```

This is just a rough outline and off the top of my head, so there's probably plenty to fix.